# NIC Teaming in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, network-bonding

I'm naive to Linux flavours (like Ubuntu, Centos, etc). I've been googling on how to setup NIC teaming in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, reading mostly using /etc/network/interfaces. But, I couldn't find  'Interfaces' and read that from 18.04 and above uses Netplan and /etc/network/**interfaces** is deprecated. So how to setup NIC teaming in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and read switching back to using the old method using interfaces is not recommended.
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-100-generic.
Will someone be able to advise, please? Thank you.